# ProviderInstaller doesn't work on emulators and caught error is not being read

Tags: java, android

In my application, I am connecting to an SSL server and in order to make it possible for API's less than 21 I need to install ProviderInstaller. Below is a preview of my code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
     try {
      ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(this);

    } catch (Exception e) {

      //Crashes the app when accessing the getMessage
      Log.i("error", e.getMessage());
   }
 }
```

This works well on device with API 16, but it doesnt work on emulators with API 16. And when I try to access the `getMessage()` error it crashes the whole application.

Why doesn't the `ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(this)` work on emulators, and also why does the application crashes when accessing the `e.getMessage()` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`installIfNeeded`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/security/ProviderInstaller) can throw two exceptions [`GooglePlayServicesRepairableException`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesRepairableException) and [`GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException), They are thrown when Google Play Services is not up-to-date or enabled and when Google Play services are not available, respectively. Possibly there is a problem with Google Play services in the emulator.

And app crashes when you access `getmessage()` is because the exception that you are catching doesn't have a message. You need to log the entire exception, not just the exception's message. You can verify this from the documentation of [getMessage](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Throwable#getMessage()) which says

> the detail message string of this Throwable instance (**which may be null**).

From documentation of GooglePlayServicesRepairableException

> In these cases, client code can use getConnectionStatusCode() in
>   conjunction with getErrorDialog(android.app.Activity, int, int) to
>   provide users with a localized Dialog that will allow users to
>   install, update, or otherwise enable Google Play services.